# Evaluating the squared term of a gaussian kernel for having a covariance matrix for multi-dimensional inputs

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, covariance, gaussian

I have two 2-dimensional numpy arrays of shape say m x d, and n x d. What is the optimized(i.e. without for loops) or the numpy way of creating the squared term of a Gaussian kernel for ultimately having a covariance matrix of size m x n.[image: Gaussian kernel: Taken from http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~duvenaud/cookbook/]

I have already checked numpy's *[outer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html)* function, but it didn't serve my purpose.

This is what an equivalent code with *for* looks like

```
difference_squared = np.zeros((x.shape[0], x_.shape[0]))
for row_iterator in range(difference_squared.shape[0]):
    for column_iterator in range(difference_squared.shape[1]):
        difference_squared[row_iterator, column_iterator] = np.sum(np.power(x[row_iterator]-x_[column_iterator], 2))
```

Comment: Show us your loopy try?

Comment: @Divakar, I have added my equivalent code snippet for computing the squared term of the Gaussian kernel in the question itself now. Take a look.

Comment: Use [SciPy cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) : `cdist(x,x_, 'sqeuclidean')`.

Comment: Thank you @Divakar, that worked.